# Finding a sub-string in an array with better time complexity (preferably in perl)

Tags: regex, algorithm, perl, data-structures

I am having an array of random alphabetical strings; the length of the array is 290K+.

Now I want to check if any of the string in the array is a sub-string of any other string present in the array.

My code

```
for my $z (0..$seq_len-1)
{
my $seq1 = $seq[$z];

for my $y (0..$seq_len-1)
{
    my $seq2 = $seq[$y];

    if($z != $y)
    {
#           my $anything = '.*';
#           my $pattern = $anything.$seq2.$anything;
        if($seq1 =~ m/$seq2/)
        {
            push @::uniq, $identifiers[$z];
            push @::duplicate, $identifiers[$y];
        }
    }
}
}
```

The code works fine but can there be a better approach to accomplish this task?

### Edit

Thanks for pointing out unnecessary usage in regexp; removed that but still not much of difference.

*Thanks in advance*

Comment: For starters - you're wrapping your `$pattern` in `.*` which is completely redundant. Regular expressions _already_ match based on substrings.

Comment: Is the array of strings sorted? Can it be?

Comment: You continue to use the shorthand `@::uniq` etc. for global variables in the `main` package. You have been warned about it before and it's a very strange semantic to adopt. I wonder where you read about it in the first place? You should use `my @uniq` outside the loop and then just `push @uniq, ...` .

Comment: @AKHolland no the array is not sorted and it can't be

Comment: @Borodin really sorry for that won't use that again..

Comment: you can improve the constant in the big O: First, you should switch the sequence of check in `$seq1 =~ /$seq2/` and pre-compile $seq1 in the outer loop. So outer loop will have `my $seq1_re = qr/$seq1/;` after `my $seq1 = $seq[$z];` and inner loop will have `if($seq2 =~ $seq1_re)` instead of `if($seq1 =~ m/$seq2/)`. Second, you should pre-calculate the lengths of the string out side the loop and then check substring only when appropriate. Use `my @seq_len = map length,@seq;` to calculate the length outside the loops. Replace `if($z != $y)` with `if($z != $y && $seq_len[$y] > $seq_len[$z])`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree).

Populate the tree with all strings, and then iterate the collection, and check if any string is a prefix of some suffix in the array, which is not the initial string already.

The idea, if you find a suffix - which a string `s` is a prefix of - it is a substring of some other string (and it is easy to find which in this DS).

This solution is pretty efficient in terms of asymptotical complexity, but requires a more complex DS for you to use.

This solution runs in `O(n*|S|)` - where `|S|` is the length of a string, which is much more efficient than your `O(n^2*R(|S|))` - where `R(|S|)` is your regex complexity.

Comment: When dealing with an algorithm whose input is a large number of strings, it's very rare than one cares about how an algorithm's performance scales as the length of the input strings increase. As such, the lengths are usually assumed to be (less than) some unspecified constant amount. For example, Merge sort is said to be O(N log N), not O(NS log N). That means the solution you suggest is O(N) as compared to the OP's O(N^2).

Comment: @ikegami I disagree, maybe it's irrelevant for an algorithm which is linear in the size of a string, but for example some regex in java (no idea how it is in pearl) run in exponential time in rare cases. GIven the fact that the length of the string is approximately a log factor of the number of strings in order for the question to be "interesting" (There are at most `|alphabet|^d` unique strings of length `d`, so if `d<<log(n)` - most of the elements are going to be duplicates anyway, and since `2^(log(n)) = n` - it matters).

Comment: @ikegami And in anycase, `O(n)` and `O(n*|S|) = O(n *logn)` are not identical, and as explained above, the question become much less relevant for `|S| << logn`

Comment: It's not linear or exponential; it's constant since the length of the strings aren't changing (only the number of strings).

Comment: @amit I found one module in Perl that helps in implementing the suffix tree but has dependencies of C lib which I am not able to install and so can't go ahead with the suffix trees. And also writing the whole code for it seems a uphill task

Comment: @Rajinder I am sorry it didn't work out. Unfortunately I am not a perl programmer and I cannot advise you on a better library. However, I do believe there must be something, suffix tree is a pretty popular DS..

Answer (score 2):

For starters:

- You're being inefficient with your pattern. The `.*` wrapping is entirely irrelevant. `/.*pattern.*/` will match the same things at `/pattern/`.
- You're making pointless comparisons - you don't need to compare bidirectionally at all, because when one string is longer than the other - it cannot be a sub string. So you can shorten your 'for' loops, so the inner (`$y`) loop starts at `$z` and just ensure you test the shorter for being a substring of the longer.
- You might find compiling some regular expressions to match each element (and reusing) will improve it - otherwise you're 'restarting' the regular expression engine each time. (see - http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators)
- You should also be able to chain matches - `A` is a substring of `AB`. Which means you don't need to individually test that `ABC`, `ABCD` etc. match both - if they match the longer one, they match the shorter.

Whether these are worth doing depends rather on the size of your lists.

Answer (score 1):

The following reduces the work from N<sup>2</sup> regexp matches to N of them. The regexp is matched against a much longer string than before, but the savings should still be quite noticeable.

```
my $encoded_seqs = "\0" . join("\0", @seqs) . "\0";
for my $seq (@seqs) {
   if (
      $encoded_seqs =~ /\0 (?: \Q$seq\E [^\0]+ | [^\0]+ \Q$seq\E [^\0]* )/x
   ) {
      print("$seq is contained by another.\n");
   } else {
      print("$seq is isn't contained by another.\n");
   }
}
```

To find one of the matches:

```
my $encoded_seqs = "\0" . join("\0", @seqs) . "\0";
for my $seq (@seqs) {
   if (
      my ($match) =
         $encoded_seqs =~ /\0 ( \Q$seq\E [^\0]+ | [^\0]+ \Q$seq\E [^\0]* )/x
   ) {
      print("$seq is contained by $match, and possibly others.\n");
   } else {
      print("$seq is isn't contained by another.\n");
   }
}
```

To find all of the matches:

```
my $encoded_seqs = "\0" . join("\0", @seqs) . "\0";
for my $seq (@seqs) {
   if (
      my @matches =
         $encoded_seqs =~ /\0 ( \Q$seq\E [^\0]+ | [^\0]+ \Q$seq\E [^\0]* )/xg
   ) {
      print("$seq is contained by @matches\n");
   } else {
      print("$seq is isn't contained by another.\n");
   }
}
```

Possibly a little bit faster:

```
$encoded_seqs =~ /\0 ( (?>[^\0]*) \Q$seq\E (?>[^\0]*) ) (?<! \0 \Q$seq\E )/xg
```

All of the above assume that NUL can't be in any of the sequences. If the sequences can contain any character, you can use the following instead:

```
# Hides "~" in a lossless way.
my @decode = qw( ! ~ );
my %encode = map { $decode[$_] => $decode[0].$_ } 0..$#decode;
sub encode(_) { return $_[0] =~ s/([!~])/$encode{$encode{$1}/gr }
sub decode(_) { return $_[0] =~ s/!(.)/$decode[$1]/sgr }

my $encoded_seqs = '~' . join('~', map encode, @seqs) . '~';
for my $seq (@seqs) {
   my $encoded_seq = encode($seq);

   # Use ~ instead of \0.
   # Use $encoded_seq instead of $seq.
   # Use decode() on the values in $match and @matches.
}
```

Comment: I am not a perl programmer - but won't it match `n` strings against a regex of size `n*|S|`, making the complexity `O(n*R(n|S|))` (where R(.) is regex's complexity), and assuming R(.) is NOT sublinear - it cannot make things any better in terms of big O notation (no idea about constants of it though).

Comment: @amit, The OP is interested in how fast the code executes (not how it scales), so I'm not too interested in the complexity. I'm sure you'll find that reducing the number of patterns that are compiled and matched from N^2 to N is going to speed up his search by a lot, even if the size of string being matched was multiplied by N in the process. It's probably not the fastest approach, but it might be fast enough.

Comment: (1) The OP does care, in his words: `Finding a sub-string in an array with better time complexity`, and for time complexity, scale does matter. (2) Not invalidating your answer in anyway, just raising a concern that should be considered, every solution probably has upsides and downsides, I think it's important to mention the trade-offs, that's all.

Comment: @amit, That's what he *said*, but I'm sure he just wants his code to run faster. I did mention the trade-offs: "The regexp is matched against a much longer string than before, but the savings should still be quite noticeable."

Comment: @amit, If you want to talk in terms of complexity, I changed O(N^2 * (Rc+Ro+Re)) to O(N + N * (Rc+Ro) + N^2 * Re). Both are O(N^2 * Re), but I greatly reduced the factor. (c=compile, o=match overhead, e=execute)

Comment: That's quite informative analysis, you should add it to the answer itself. Also, shouldn't it be `Re(N)` (and similarly) - or can we assume perl's regex take linear time?

Comment: @ikegami My string size vary from 100 - 100000 characters; so in case I make it as a single string will it be a good option

Comment: My solution reduces number of regex patterns from N^2 to N. So yeah, it will help no matter how long your strings are. How much? That's for you to find out. If it's good enough, great! If not, amit's solution should be faster (though it'll be more work).

Comment: @ikegami thanks I tried your logic and the run completed in about 2 an a half hours where earlier it was taking more than a day to complete

Comment: @ikegami a new requirement has come up; now I also have to return the string to which my substring matched. And also the regex you have used doesn't match the exact string (because same strings are also present in the array)... I am really sorry if I am asking too much

Comment: See update. Also fixed a bug where x wasn't considered to be in xy and yx. Both the bug fix and the new feature will slow things down :( Especially the new feature.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding complexity and runtime here:

```
    my $anything = '.*';
    my $pattern = $anything.$seq2.$anything;
    if($seq1 =~ m/$pattern/)
```

The `.*` before and after `$seq2` serve no purpose, because `/foo/` is functionally identical to `/.*foo.*/`.